# Change icon on toggle jquery

Tags: jquery

I was able to change the text as well as icon on show/hide option by clicking a button.However, when icon applies to the button it changes font family.

If i add class to the button it applies to the font awesome icon css so it changes the font family on the icon and it is not appearing.

Is there a way to set font family for the text alone not affecting font awesome icons.

HTML code:

```
 <button class="btn btn-default" type="search" id="filter">
            <i class="fa fa-down"></i>
                Show 
</button>
```

Jquery:

```
$("#filter").click(function(e) {
            $(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle("fast");

if ($.trim($(this).text()) === 'Show') {
    $(this).text('Hide');
    $(this).addClass('fa fa-up');
//  $(this).addClass('custom-font');
} else {
    $(this).text('Show Filter');  
    $(this).addClass('fa fa-down');
  }

return false; 

    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two issues. You are replacing the entire contents of your button with `.text()`, instead of just the text node. So, you need to replace just the text node in order to keep the icon. Then, you need to change the class on the icon instead of the button.

```
if ($.trim($(this).text()) === 'Show') {
    $(this).contents().last()[0].textContent = 'Hide';
    $(this).find('.fa').removeClass('fa-down').addClass('fa-up');
//  $(this).addClass('custom-font');
} else {
    $(this).contents().last()[0].textContent = 'Show Filter';  
    $(this).find('.fa').removeClass('fa-up').addClass('fa-down');
}
```

Alternatively, you could just use `.html` to replace the old html with the new.

```
if ($.trim($(this).text()) === 'Show') {
    $(this).html('<i class="fa fa-up"></i>Hide');
//  $(this).addClass('custom-font');
} else {
    $(this).html('<i class="fa fa-down"></i>Show Filter');
}
```